# Подскажите плагин для галереи?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

Нужен плагин, в котом при нажатии на одну картинку, во всплывающем окне открывается например 5 штук, то-есть каждая отдельная картинка это галерея о своими изображениями. Может кто знает?
Лишь бы, был пример использования и документация

Comment: https://codepen.io/rademade/pen/rYwWZo

Comment: https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=slick+%2B+lightbox

Answer (score 2):

Вот два пакета. Может быть подойдут.
Но мне кажется проще своё написать.

[Галерея №1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blueimp-gallery)

[Галерея №2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-js)

Пример с CodePen [Спасибо @MaximLensky  за предоставленную ссылку]

---

**Не рекомендуется использование jquery.**

### Возможны проблемы при использовании web components.

Используемые библиотеки

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.min.js

js код:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.js-gallery').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    prevArrow: '<span class="gallery-arrow mod-prev">Prev</span>',
    nextArrow: '<span class="gallery-arrow mod-next">Next</span>'
  });

  $('.js-gallery').slickLightbox({
    src: 'src',
    itemSelector: '.js-gallery-popup img',
    background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)'
  });
});
```

html:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="content-title">Gallery</h1>

  <div class="gallery js-gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-img-holder js-gallery-popup">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/500" alt="" class="gallery-img">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-img-holder js-gallery-popup">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/500" alt="" class="gallery-img">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-img-holder js-gallery-popup">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="" class="gallery-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
html
  background: #F7E4C5

.content
  position: relative
  display: block
  width: 100%
  padding: 20px

.content-title
  display: block
  margin-bottom: 40px
  font-size: 25px
  line-height: 27px
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif

.gallery
  position: relative
  display: block
  max-width: 500px
  max-height: 300px
  margin: auto
  border-radius: 4px
  overflow: hidden

  .slick-list
    overflow: hidden

  .slick-slide
    outline: none !important

.gallery-arrow
  position: absolute
  top: 50%
  transform: translateY(-50%)
  width: 40px
  height: 40px
  font-size: 14px
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif
  line-height: 40px
  text-align: center
  background-color: #E6E6E6
  z-index: 10
  cursor: pointer
  transition: background .3s ease

  &:hover
    background: #D0DFE6

  &.mod-prev
    left: 0
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0

  &.mod-next
    right: 0
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px


.gallery-item
  position: relative
  float: left
  vertical-align: middle
  text-align: center

.gallery-img-holder
  display: inline-block
  width: auto
  height: auto
  max-width: 500px
  max-height: 500px

.gallery-img
  width: 100%
  height: 100%

.slick-lightbox

  .slick-arrow
    z-index: 10
```

[Результат](https://codepen.io/rademade/pen/rYwWZo)

Comment: Не вижу примера, где к отдельной картинке отдельная галерея

Comment: @Aleksys https://codepen.io/rademade/pen/rYwWZo так ?

Comment: Серёга красава..

Comment: Использовать jquery сегодня это маветон.

Comment: Нет не совсем, речь шла о том чтобы например есть 6 картинок. При открытие каждой из них есть 6 других.

Comment: ну не сложно собрать на этом примере.